# First error: Query of LOB fields caused heap usage to exceed limit

Tags: apex, soql, batch, limits, heap

I simply try to execute a batch job and execute a SOQL inside the execute() method as below with having,

- execute() method has the line **List results = (List)database.query(query);** , and
- start() method queries 10000 records (**SELECT Id FROM statustracking__c  LIMIT :recordsLimit**)[**see the note], and
- batch size is 2000 and,
- I do not have any long text fields/attachments or such kind of large content fields

trying to execute the above batch resulting the below error;

**"Query of LOB fields caused heap usage to exceed limit."**

Can someone explain/suggest;

- why the error is thrown even the record limit is 10000?
- are there any alternative ways that I could process 100000 except PK chunking? (this much is what I actually want to process)

"query" variable in the first point contains the below SOQL;

```
SELECT ownervalue__c, 
   managerlevel3__c, 
   isdeleted, 
   ownerid__c, 
   previous_owner__c, 
   enddate__c, 
   isteammanager__c, 
   iscreatorloggedin__c, 
   id, 
   networkresponsevalue__c, 
   createddate, 
   createddatelist__c, 
   managerlevel1__c, 
   statusduration__c, 
   status__c, 
   fieldschanged__c, 
   ownername__c, 
   startdate__c, 
   assignedbyfillinbox__c, 
   createdbyid, 
   statusvalid__c, 
   lastmodifiedbyid, 
   previous_owner_id__c, 
   recordtypeid, 
   agent__c, 
   duration__c, 
   lastmodifieddate, 
   ischannelmanager__c, 
   businesstime__c, 
   durationmins__c, 
   previous_owner_name__c, 
   day_of_the_week__c, 
   networkcommentsvalue__c, 
   systemmodstamp, 
   durationhours__c, 
   managerlevel2__c, 
   creatorrole__c, 
   ignore__c, 
   fax__c, 
   network__c, 
   businesshours__c, 
   business_hours_status__c, 
   case__c, 
   name, 
   escalationtier__c, 
   business_hour_duration__c, 
   ccmanager__c, 
   subsequentstatusvalue__c, 
   start_date_hour__c, 
   durationseconds__c, 
   statusvalue__c, 
   case_contact_id__c, 
   creatorprofile__c 
   FROM   statustracking__c 
   WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT statustracking__c 
              FROM   archivelog__c 
              WHERE  sobjecttype__c = 'StatusTracking__c' 
                     AND ( status__c = 'Archived' 
                            OR status__c = 'Failed To Archive' 
                            OR status__c = 'Failed To Delete Original' )) 
   AND createddate < :olderThan 
   ORDER  BY createddate ASC
```

> NOTE: ** queries all the records with the limit 10000 and moved the filtering to the execute() method, it was before in start() method and thrown the "First error: [**REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG**] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped." error.

Comment: You are querying lot of fields right! where you are doing that? Is it in start method or execute method?

Answer (score 5):

The query you are executing in your `execute()` method does not appear to contain any reference to or filter based upon the `scope` parameter received by `execute()`.

What this means is that in terms of executing this query, what you do in your `start()` method and what you set your batch size to are both irrelevant. You're just running this query in an asynchronous context apropos of nothing, and you're hitting a limit - either the heap limit or the query processing time limit.

Absent further details on your data model and your code, the query looks to me like a major performance problem. While `CreatedDate` is indexed, your `NOT IN` subquery looks like it is probably very inefficient, particularly if - but not only if - `ArchiveLog__c.SObjectType__c` and `Status__c` aren't indexed and the data volume in that object is large. And you are pulling back a very large number of fields on potentially a very large number of records.

I would recommend you do one of two things:

- Construct a more idiomatic batch class, where you execute a single query in your `start()` method and process each batch in `execute()` without trying to perform additional broad-based queries. If possible given the full details of your data model and objective, tune your query to make this possible by using indexed fields, avoiding negative criteria, and following other [best practices for large data volumes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf). The Query Plan tool may help you achieve this.
- If you are not able to do so, ensure that the query you perform in your `execute()` method is filtered by the `Ids` of the records in the scope for *this* batch. This will allow you to dramatically limit the bounds of each `execute()` query in terms of both execution time, via an `Id IN :idSet` type filter, and in terms of the heap space consumed. Note that pursuing this route means that your batch class will ultimately have to traverse *all* of the records of `StatusTracking__c` in your database, which may make the overall performance of the process unacceptable.
- In either route, tune your batch size to make each invocation of `execute()` realistically completable within a single transaction. 2000 is a very large batch. If you encounter limits issues within a single batch, turn the batch size down until you're able to complete them successfully.

PK chunking is a technique you can use to execute very large scale queries with the Bulk API, not via Batch Apex.